# Vertically and horizontally centering two items within a parent div that is part of a flex-row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4...

Suppose I have the following flex-row inside of a div, with a font-awesome icon in each `port-item` and a small text instance below each icon. I'd like to vertically and horizontally center both the font-awesome icon and the text within their parent `port-item` div, and my 2+ hours worth of effort and searching have been in vain.

I imagine I have searched through about 15 topics on this site and arrived at nothing. I think my setup is unique due to the flex-row.

```
<div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row text-white">
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing1">
      <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i>
      Thing 1
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing2">
      <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i>
      Thing 2
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing3">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> 
      Thing 3
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-twilight" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing4">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil d-block"></i>
      Thing 4
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-citrus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing5">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt d-block"></i>
      Thing 5
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing6">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i>
      Thing 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS acting on this region:

```
.port-item{
        width: 16.6666667%;
        .fa{
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
    }
```

The 16.66667% is to ensure that each of the 6 port items take up and equal width of the flex row, which works fine. The font-size change is to clean up a responsiveness issue I had. Ignore the custom theme background classes; I made them myself. Ignore the data-targets and data-toggles as well; those come into play with some collapsing down further in the code, but I included them for completeness sake.

Picture of the issue:

[image: Flex-row centering problem]

As you can see, neither the font-awesome icon nor the text are aligned either horizontally or vertically.

EDIT: After ZNaneswar's edited answer, using my actual bar:

[image: Second try]

Comment: Try adding `display: flex; align-items: center` to the `port-item` class.

Comment: That moved the text to the right of the icon (it began below, which is where I need it) and didn't center either horizontally.

Comment: `flex-direction: column` or `flex-direction: row` whichever works. Could you please share a screen shot, so that it is easier to visualise.

Comment: Just use `text-align:center;`to `.port-item`

Comment: Gladly. This is the picture without any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I haven't missed something here, you should make the `port-item` a flex *column* container, which will stack the icon and text vertical (the text will become an [anonymous](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#anonymous) flex item), and then will `align-items`/`justify-content` center them horizontally/vertically.

```css
.port-item {
  width: 16.6666667%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row text-white">
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing1">
      <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i> Home
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing2">
      <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i> CV
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing3">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> Research
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing4">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil d-block"></i> Teaching
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing5">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt d-block"></i> Lifting
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing6">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i> Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

add `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.port-item{
        width: 16.6666667%;
         word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align:center;
        .fa{
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
        
    }
    p{
         
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row text-white">
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing1">
      <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i>
      Thing 1
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing2">
      <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i>
      Thing 2
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing3">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> 
      Thing 3
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-twilight" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing4">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil d-block"></i>
      Thing 4
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-citrus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing5">
      <i class="fa fa-bolt d-block"></i>
      Lifting
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#thing6">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i>
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my updated post containing a picture of your most recent suggestion, applied to my real-life situation. Not even all of the fa icons are centered, in addition to the text looking strange.

Comment: If possible can you provide screenshot of output or just any layout

Comment: Check my updated post. It contains a screenshot of my row after applying your most recent suggestion.

Comment: No I'm asking for screenshot of required output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157115/discussion-between-johnny-apple-and-znaneswar).